# File: \boot\bcd Status: 0xc00000e9 windows 8

Tags: windows-8, boot

I am having this error for quite a few months. When the problem occurs, my windows freezes at boot time with black screen. After few reset attempts, sometimes it shows the entitled error. after few attempts, the windows starts but everything become slow. If I again restart, it works well. But at a point windows never starts and I have to reinstall it. I have already reinstalled 3/4 times in the past 2/3 months. I checked for any HDD errors with EASEUS Partition Master Home Edition with surface test, `chkdisk` at boot time etc for my C drive and F drive but no errors found. Startup repair also fails to solve the problem.

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \Boot\BCD

  Status: 0xc00000e9
```

My laptop's info:

Model: Dell n5110 corei5
OS: Windows 8 PRO 64 bit
Anti-virus:  Avast Home edition

Additional info: My Program Files, Program Files (x86) and Users directory is located at F drive and linked with symbolic link (mklink). Also I have changed these basic locations from regedit. I also use eclipse android intelx86 emulator, virtualbox and Genymotion emulator most often.

Comment: the error means STATUS_UNEXPECTED_IO_ERROR. Check your HDD for errors (HDD diag tool)

Comment: Can you please suggest any good free tool? I checked with EASEUS Partition Master Home Edition and found nothing.

Comment: try a tool from your HDD manufacture.

Comment: I am going to try with SeaTools now to see what happens.

Comment: I used Dell Diagnostics. It found no error, it shows everything's fine. I don't know the manufacturer's name, only the model is visible. SeaTools can't detect my HDD. The problem is not appearing right now but it may appear very soon. I had to reinstall windows everyday for past 3 days.

Comment: please provide pictures of this tool: http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html What is the health status?

Comment: Wow! This tool actually shows some errors! http://s27.postimg.org/nyx7k5xn7/Untitled.png
http://s27.postimg.org/ic0umov4j/Untitled1.png

Comment: you should replace the HDD.

Comment: upps!! Could you please tell me why?

Comment: because of the errors you see in the picture. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes

Comment: I mean there is no other solutions of fixes?

Comment: no, there is no other solution. replace it asap and backup your data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HDD is damaged as you can see in the picture of the [SMART attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes):

[image]

**Reallocated Sectors Count:**

> Count of reallocated sectors. When the hard drive finds a
>   read/write/verification error, it marks that sector as "reallocated"
>   and transfers data to a special reserved area (spare area). This
>   process is also known as remapping, and reallocated sectors are called
>   "remaps".
>
> As the count of reallocated sectors increases, the read/write speed
>   tends to become worse because the drive head is forced to seek to the
>   reserved area whenever a remap is accessed. If sequential access speed
>   is critical, the remapped sectors can be manually marked as bad blocks
>   in the file system in order to prevent their use.

**Current Pending Sector Count:**

> Count of "unstable" sectors (waiting to be remapped, because of
>   unrecoverable read errors). If an unstable sector is subsequently read
>   successfully, the sector is remapped and this value is decreased. Read
>   errors on a sector will not remap the sector immediately (since the
>   correct value cannot be read and so the value to remap is not known,
>   and also it might become readable later);
>
> **This is a serious shortcoming, for if such a drive contains marginal sectors that consistently fail only after some time has passed
>   following a successful write operation, then the drive will never
>   remap these problem sectors.**

**Uncorrectable Sector Count**

> The total count of uncorrectable errors when reading/writing a sector.
>   A rise in the value of this **attribute indicates defects of the disk
>   surface and/or problems in the mechanical subsystem.**

Backup all data and replace the HDD very soon.