# Unexpected I/O Error after a reboot when installing windows update with a brand new SSD

Tags: windows-8.1, memory, ssd

I have this error : [image]

It happened after rebooting cause Windows update was stuck ot 70%.

I recently changed my Hard Drive for a SSD cause it started crashing (the hard drive was slow AF). 
My computer is old and I suspect the memory, anyone has an idea ?

- Video card : Sapphire 100283-3L Radeon HD 5770 Video Card - 1GB GDDR5, PCI-Express 2.0, CrossFireX Ready, Dual DVI, Display Port, HDMI
- MB : Gigabyte 880GM-UD2H Motherboard - Socket AM3, AMD 880G, MicroATX, USB,     - HDMI, DVI, PCIe, RAID
- CPU : AMD HDT55TFBGRBOX Phenom II X6 1055T Processor - Six Core, 6MB L3 Cache, 3MB L2 Cache, 2.80GHz, Socket AM3, Fan, Retail
- Ram : Corsair Dominator PC10666 RAM - 4GB, (2x2GB) DDR3, 1333MHz, Dual Path, Dual Channel
- PSupply : Ultra LSP750 750-Watt Power Supply - ATX, SATA-Ready, SLI-Ready, 135mm Fan, Sleeved Cables, Matte Finish, 3-Year Warranty

Comment: What are the specs of your computer?  Did you back off the upgrade?  If so you could use Speccy (https://www.piriform.com/speccy/download) to get the full specs of your computer.  This might help you and others figure out what's going on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File: \boot\bcd Status: 0xc00000e9 windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/696877/file-boot-bcd-status-0xc00000e9-windows-8)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 this is not a duplicate. My SSD is new, i'm pretty sure it's not the problem.

Comment: The error means your drive, or the drive subsystem, are malfunctioning.  You've provided no research to show the drive is not the problem (or research of anything regarding your problem).  New hardware malfunctions ALL THE TIME (more than older in-use stuff).  So, do as the others in the other question have done, _Test your drive_.  Run a SMART check.  Run a disk check.  Try the drive in another computer.

Comment: Also if you "suspect the memory", then try known-good memory, and/or test the existing memory.  As-is you've offered us nothing to go on other than an error code, so I don't see how you could get an accurate answer.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 got the issue with 1 hard drive and 1ssd